# backbone.js https

Tags: ssl, backbone.js, https

Been googling all morning but can't find an answer.

The official documentation does not even have the words "https" or "ssl" on it.

Currently I have something like:

```
var A = backbone.Collection.extend({
  url : "a"
});
```

is there a way to make the url https, without using absolute path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can change the URL to HTTPS since it's just building a relative URL to your location.  Why not do something like this:

```
var A = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function() {
    return "https://" + this.document.location.host + "/a";
  }
});
```

Comment: ya, looks like i'll have to put it together myself

Comment: in my scenario, i have to use the relative path because i need parts of path after host, so i have to 1. strip out # and whatever after; 2. slice off http://; then 3. put https in front and "/a" at back; so i thought it's a bit ugly

Comment: Unfortunately I think you'll need to do it programatically since I don't know of a way to just say "make it SSL".  If you use the `location` object, you should be able to parse the URL rather painlessly.