# Backbone.js requests over https

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, backbone.js, https

I'm working on a single page app that uses Backbone.js and marionette on the front end, and Django with Tastypie on the back. I just added a ssl certificate to the web server, and redirected all the http traffic to https.

Everything seems to work fine except for the backbone (sync) request that continues to send request over http, causing the browser to block those requests, and I don't know how to tell backbone to use https by default.

The backbone models url/urlroot are relative so they should take the same protocol as the rest of the site right? Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [backbone.js https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565676/backbone-js-https)

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.sync` is a wrapper around [jQuery.ajax(...)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in the end.  You are correct that Backbone (via jQuery) should use the protocol of the hosting page.  And the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) dictates the browser reject any request made to a different host, port, or protocol.

All this suggests the way you're hosting the page is getting jQuery's signals crossed.  If you access the page directly via `HTTPS` instead of relying on the `HTTP` --> `HTTPS` redirect, does it work?  If so, the problem isn't a Backbone one, but a hosting one.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've removed the redirect, allowing only https request and backbone is still submitting via http. weird.

Comment: Craziness.  Further stabbing-in-the-dark:  how is Backbone/jQuery included on the hosting page?  Using `<script src="http://..."></script>` or something?  If  so, you could also try loading the scripts via the protocol-agnostic `<script src="//..."></script>`

Comment: the scripts are compressed via django-compressor and served via s3 and https still don't know the cause :S